# unable to understand connection establishment code

Tags: java, jsch, remote-connection

I am beginner in Java and as such I am having difficulty in understanding a piece of code.At [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583846/failed-to-remotely-execute-r-script-which-loads-library-rhdfs)
SO post the first two lines create a connection instance:

```
/* Create a connection instance */
Connection conn = new Connection(hostname);
/* Now connect */
conn.connect();
```

I am unable to get which library needs to be imported to support this? The post mentions use of `JSch` in the beginning but when I tried it then I couldn't where in `JSch` `Connection` class is declared? Any help will be useful for me.

Comment: If you want to learn how to create a database connection, I would go to a more basic source, such as this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Comment: @mickey is that a database connection? The post is related to remote execution of R scripts

Comment: My mistake, your example is connect to a remote server, not a db.

Comment: @mickey in that regards only how does `Connection` is imported?

Comment: There seem to be two or three different things called Jsch. Keep looking.

Comment: @EJP I looked around Jsch but all I found is the `jcraft` one which I tried but was unable to create `Connection` instance

Comment: Well I looked around too and I found two or three. Obviously the jcraft one isn't the right one. Keep looking. If I found more, you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JCraft JSCH can be used to perform SFTP and run remote commands with an SSH connection.

It does not use a Connection class.  In JSCH you create a Session object, which contains connection information.  You then connect the session object, then create Channel objects to send input/receive output.

[Here is the session API documentation for JSCH.](http://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/Session.html)

[Here are some examples from JCraft.](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/)

There have been quite a few JSCH questions asked here on Stack overflow, [some of which include working code you could use to try it out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405885/any-good-jsch-examples)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the `Connection` class you mention is [`ch.ethz.ssh2.Connection`](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/Connection.html).  It's mentioned in `import` directives in code samples [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jsch/mailman/message/6402065/) and [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mina/sshd/tags/sshd-0.7.0/sshd-core/src/test/java/org/apache/sshd/ScpTest.java).  This class looks to be in a JAR named ganymed-ssh2.jar.

Comment: The poster in the linked question states he is using something called Jsch. Ganymed is a good SSH library, and it does have a Connection class, but it isn't called Jsch.

Comment: @EJP: The class I linked to has the constructor and all methods mentioned in the code sample in the linked question, and the [Session](http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/javadoc/ch/ethz/ssh2/Session.html) class also has the methods mentioned in that code sample.  So I believe that the Ganymed library is being used.  Perhaps the poster in the linked question was mistaken about using JSch?