# R-Hadoop integration - how to connect R to remote hdfs

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs, rhadoop

I have a case where I will be running R code on a data that will be downloaded from Hadoop. Then, the output of the R code will be uploaded back to Hadoop as well. Currently, I am doing it manually and I would like to avoid this manual downloading/uploading process.

Is there a way I can do this in R by connecting to hdfs? In other words, in the beginning of the R script, it connects to Hadoop and reads the data, then in the end it uploads the output data to Hadoop again. Are there any packages that can be used? Any changes required in Hadoop server or R?

I forgot to note the important part: R and Hadoop are on different servers.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to download data from hdfs?  In general with hadoop, the point should be to bring the computation to the data.  Not saying there's never a scenario where you would want to do that, just curious as to your use case.

Comment: I am not familiar how I would run R functions on a data in hadoop without reading it in R first.

Comment: are you able to install R on your Hadoop servers? Downloading the data to your R server seems costly...

Comment: No, we are not able to install R on  Hadoop server . The size of the data also won't be an issue. This will be done on a regular basis so we would like to just do everything in R if possible.

Comment: Is this an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583846/failed-to-remotely-execute-r-script-which-loads-library-rhdfs

Comment: Why the tag rhadoop?

Comment: Any other tag suggestions? Or any other place where I can ask this question?

Answer (score 0):

Install the package rmr2 , you will have an option of **from.dfs** function which can solves your requirement of getting the data from HDFS as mentioned below:

`input_hdfs <- from.dfs("path_to_HDFS_file",format="format_columns")`

For Storing the results back into HDFS, you can do like 
`write.table(data_output,file=pipe(paste('hadoop dfs -put -', path_to_output_hdfs_file, sep='')),row.names=F,col.names=F,sep=',',quote=F)`

(or)
You can use rmr2 **to.dfs** function to store back into HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

So... Have you found a solution for this?

Some months ago I have stumbled upon the same situation. After fiddling around for some time with the Revolution Analytics packages, I couldn't find a way for it to work in the situation where R and Hadoop are on different servers.

I tried using webHDFS, which at the time worked for me.
You can find an R package for webhdfs acess [here](https://github.com/saurfang/rwebhdfs)

The package is not available on CRAN you need to run:

```
devtools::install_github(c("saurfang/rwebhdfs"))
```

(yeah... You will need the devtools package)